# Bootstrap: Page does not load correctly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning `Bootstrap` now and it is literally my first time trying something.
I have followed an example from the book and it is supposed to work.

However, when running the page the result is different.

Here is my `.html` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Bootstrap Grid System</title>
        <link rel="styleheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
<body>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h4>Column 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h4>Column 2</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It supposed to generate 2 columns on the left and the right:

[image]

But it generates the following:

[image]

I'm not sure really why? Any ideas?

Comment: Put your scripts either in the head of the document or before the end of the body. Then check to see if you're getting any errors in the browser's console. Are the paths to all your included files correct?

Comment: use CDN first and check whether its work --- >  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: I tried that combination before. And all the paths are correct

Comment: try with Bootstrap CDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I tried according to this link: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-get-started.php

and it seemed better. if you'll look at the console with your example, it will tell you that "bootstrap's js requires jquery"

i tried it like this and it was better:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap Grid System</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional Bootstrap theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


</head>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h4>Column 1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h4>Column 2</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

maybe it's about the jquery version. try it out

Comment: @gene - Why was this the answer to your issue?

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I copied the links as they are showed and it worked. Also, I moved script reference in the end of the body

Comment: you're welcome. by the way, I heartily recommand the link i attached. that tutorial is very good

Answer (score 0):

Check with firebug or a similar developer tool, if your files (css/bootstrap.css, js/bootstrap.js) are located in your folders and they are "included" in your html.

You can use Bootstrap CDN too, to make sure that css and js are loaded.

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your bootstrap javascript file is not being loaded. Try to change it to this:

```
<head>   
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```